# Sumo simulator for urban traffic simulation

Tags: simulation, sumo

For urban traffic simulator, we can use Sumo simulator with other simulators like Omnet++ or Matlab or Ns2/3.

I know Sumo can model mobility and other simulators coupled to Sumo for communication protocols or communication networks.

While it is possible to simulate VANET with just using Matlab.

What is the difference between them (SUMO and others or just using Matlab)?

How can we find which is better?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how much influence the traffic situation has to your scenario. If you are just interested in checking whether your protocol works even if two vehicles drive at 200 km/h in opposite directions but there is no interaction with other vehicles, you do not need SUMO. But if your scenarios involve jams or complex junctions and you want (more or less) realistic trajectories for interacting vehicles you are better off with a traffic simulation like SUMO (especially if you want to run on real world scenarios importing data from OpenStreetMap etc.).